# Expected Value formula

Tags: vb.net, math, statistics

I have a table as follows

Day Savings

1   :   251

2   :   722

3   :   1132

4   :   1929

5   :   3006

6   :   4522

7   :   8467

...

14   :   x

These savings are growing day by day, I want to find a formula to expect the final value of day 14 which is x!

Comment: yes i am trying to write a code to expect value of x, in VB.net, I am new to this website i have no idea how to do the things properly

Comment: We need more details on your problem.  What's the formula?  What have you tried already, and how is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the data in any detail, but it seems like an exponential growth situation.  If that's the case, then you can estimate the growth rate by fitting an exponential curve to the data using [least squares approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488747/least-square-approximation-for-exponential-functions) to get an estimated interest rate, `r`.  If you find the data not conducive to that, you could try fitting it to some other curve.  You can then use the estimated interest rate to compute the expected funds using the standard `a = p*exp(r*i)` where `p` is the initial principal and `i` is the elapsed time.

This all assumes compounding interest which is an exponential growth situation.  If that assumption is incorrect, this approach is probably not going to work for you.